How were the asymmetric recovery ranges in Table A5 of Appendix F from AOAC determined?
I am trying to understand how the recovery ranges in Table A5 of Appendix F from AOAC (https://www.aoac.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/app_f.pdf) were determined.
I did not understand how the asymmetric intervals were determined, it seems to have something to do with low concentration.
Could someone explain this, or inform me where I can find the original study?

Please edit the post to include relevant information from the link. Few peope will read the link only to answer the Q
